# how to verify smart contract without error?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, truffle, ico

I deployed an ethereum smart contract 3 months ago, I kept the original source code and tried to verify it today, but could not make it. It keeps telling me 'Sorry! The Compiled Contract ByteCode for 'hahaCoin' does NOT match the Contract Creation Code'.

I have also deployed a new one with same code on ropsten testnet and is able to verify it the next minute. At this stage, I am guessing it was because the compiler version mismatch, so I end up trying compilers from list one by one, and copy the source byte code to compare with the correct one. I could not remember the compiler version I used, because I was using online remix solidity IDE to publish my contract.

These are some of the byte code I copied:

```
correct:
608060405234801561001057600080fd5b50604051604080611d2d8339810180604052810190808051906020019092919080519060200190929190505050336000806101000a81548173ffff
0.4.23
608060405234801561001057600080fd5b5060048054600160a060020a033316600160a060020a031990911681179091556b204fce5e3e250261100000006000818155918252600160205260
608060405234801561001057600080fd5b5060048054600160a060020a033316600160a060020a031990911681179091556b204fce5e3e250261100000006000818155918252600160205260
608060405234801561001057600080fd5b5060048054600160a060020a033316600160a060020a031990911681179091556b204fce5e3e250261100000006000818155918252600160205260
608060405234801561001057600080fd5b5033600460006101000a81548173ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff021916908373ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
608060405234801561001057600080fd5b5033600460006101000a81548173ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff021916908373ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
0.4.24
608060405234801561001057600080fd5b5033600460006101000a81548173ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff021916908373ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
608060405234801561001057600080fd5b5060048054600160a060020a033316600160a060020a031990911681179091556b204fce5e3e250261100000006000818155918252600160205260
0.4.25
608060405234801561001057600080fd5b5060048054600160a060020a031916339081179091556b204fce5e3e250261100000006000818155918252600160205260409091205561092480610
608060405234801561001057600080fd5b5033600460006101000a81548173ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff021916908373fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
0.4.22
6060604052341561000f57600080fd5b33600460006101000a81548173ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff021916908373ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff160
0.4.21
6060604052341561000f57600080fd5b33600460006101000a81548173ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff021916908373ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
```

and I have no luck here trying and wasting my time. Does anyone have similar issue, and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

ok, I found out the solution.
I was selecting the wrong compiler version, the correct one for me was 0.4.25-nightly.2018.5.16+commit.3897c367.

This is one of the worst debugging experience ever, I just choose compiler version one by one to test it out.